# getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection warning on android searchbox

Tags: android, android-actionbar, logcat

I get the following set of errors when leaving the searchbox on my actionbar, either by selecting one of the listview items, or by selecting the back button to return to the activity.

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

The search functionality is working as desired, but the log is filling up with the error messages.

I have looked at all the similar questions, but unfortunately all deal with issues with edittext elements. I would use this code in the onPause event if I could figure out how to reference the system search widget.

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(???myEditText???.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Relevant code from Main Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    familyAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

    return true;
}
```

Code from Adapter:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (familyFilter == null) {
        familyFilter = new FamilyFilter();
    }
    return familyFilter;
}

private class FamilyFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Family> tempList = new ArrayList<Family>();
            for (Family family : mFamilyList) {
                if (family.getLocalName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    tempList.add(family);
                }
            }
            filterResults.count = tempList.size();
            filterResults.values = tempList;
        } else {
            filterResults.count = mFamilyList.size();
            filterResults.values = mFamilyList;
        }

        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        mFilteredList = (ArrayList<Family>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I'm stumped what to do next.